# How to display response value in flatpickr jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, flatpickr

I got return from response, but to display in Input tag using flatpickr jQuery?

console.log response value: `2022-04-12T04:00:00Z`
[image]

Field is blank, should be display value from response.
[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-4">Datetime</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="editActDate">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$("#editActDate").flatpickr({ // https://flatpickr.js.org/options/
    enableTime: true,
    altInput: true,
    allowInput: true,
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'api_url',
    type : 'POST',
    data: { param: params },
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response); // received return value and success
        if (response.status == "success"){
            $('#editActDate').prop(response.data[0].act_date); // Have tried but not appear
            $('#editActDate').text(response.data[0].act_date); // Have tried but not appear
            $('#editActDate').val(response.data[0].act_date); // Have tried but not appear
        }
    },
    error: function(e){
        errorToast(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use flatpicker's api, specifically the [`setDate()` method](https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#setdatedate-triggerchange-datestrformat):

Define a ***flatpickr** **instance*** and assign to a variable:

```
const myFlatpickrInstance = $("#editActDate").flatpickr({
    enableTime: true,
    altInput: true,
    allowInput: true,
});
```

Apply `setDate()` to it:

```
 myFlatpickrInstance.setDate(response.data[0], true);
```

Comment: i got this error when apply above code. `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).setDate is not a function`

Comment: How did u install jQuery and flatpickr? via npm? via `<script src=''>` tag?

Comment: yes both been installed. top is jquery, bottom is flatpickr

Comment: ok have tried something and solved my problem. btw thank for your respond

Comment: I edited my answer, you probably get that error because `setDate()` is a flatpickr's method, not a jQuery one.
So, you have to create a flatpickr instance before and apply the method to that instance.

Answer (score 0):

I just add this and solve my problem.

```
$("#editActDate").flatpickr({ // https://flatpickr.js.org/options/
    enableTime: true,
    altInput: true,
    allowInput: true,
    defaultDate: response.data[0].act_date, // I add this
});
```